# Only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index how to resolve

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

File "C:/Users/Benji/PycharmProjects/Code/ANOTHER22.py", line 57, in generator

```
x_class[np.array(y)[i]].append(np.array(x)[i])
```

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

```
x_class = [[] for i in range(len(np.unique(y)))]
    for i in range(len(x)):
        x_class[y[i]].append(x[i])
```

Comment: What is `y[i]`?

Comment: ```(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()   .... x= x_train,  and y = y_train

Comment: Perhaps you could check what type of data `y` stores. Is it an array of integers? If it is an array of floats for example, you cannot use it as an index of `x_class`.